# How to "Ignore change tracking" in Sql Schema Compare?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to ignore "ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING" in SQL Schema Compare?

Comment: What you want to do and why do you want to ignore "ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING" ?

Comment: I am creating a sqlproj (for tracking schema changes) for a database that has change tracking enabled. And I want to be able to duplicate this same schema (from sqlproj) with the option without change tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is a lightweight solution that provides an efficient change tracking mechanism for applications. Typically, to enable applications to query for changes to data in a database and access information that is related to the changes, application developers had to implement custom change tracking mechanisms.

According my experience, we can not ignore the "ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING" in SQL Schema Compare.

But when the the schema/database duplicated, we can disable **Change Tracking** manually:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = OFF
```

For more details, please reference: [Enable and Disable Change Tracking (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#disable-change-tracking-for-a-database-or-table).

Hope this helps.